# Add event on top of mizzao:autocomplete package in meteor

Tags: meteor

I am using [mizzao:autocomplete](https://atmospherejs.com/mizzao/autocomplete) package in one of my search field in my application. Autocomplete is working fine and auto-suggestion is coming from my DB. As per given in the usage documentation this package using separate template for showing the suggestion list. Usually when someone select from given suggestion, the list will disappear and selected value appears in the textbox.

Now what i want is manually trigger some event in `title` template & do some extra stuff in `autoComplete` template when someone select some suggestion..

**autoComplete.html**

```
<template name="autoComplete">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <h4>Auto Complete</h4>
        {{> inputAutocomplete settings=settings id="jobTitle" class="form-control" name="title" placeholder="Job Title" autocomplete="off"}}
    </div>
</template>

<template name="titles">
    {{title}}
</template>
```

**autoComplete.js**

```
Template.autoComplete.helpers({
    settings : function() {
        return {
            position: 'bottom',
            limit: 10,
            rules: [
                {
                    collection: JobTitleCollection,
                    field: 'title',
                    matchAll: true,
                    template: Template.titles
                }
            ]
        };
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the `autocompleteselect` event, as [described in the docs](https://github.com/mizzao/meteor-autocomplete#detecting-selections).

```
Template.foo.events({
  "autocompleteselect input": function(event, template, doc) {
    console.log("selected ", doc);
  }
});
```

(Disclaimer: I am [mizzao](https://github.com/mizzao).)

Comment: great! one more query to you @mizzao. I am not using subscription in my application. So, what i am doing is making server call take all the data and store it in the client collection (mini-mongo) & using client collection in `rules : [...]`. Is that a good way? **Future Scope:** when `Meteor.methods` support we will get?

Comment: That sounds right: just make a `new Mongo.Collection(null)` and load it up with data from a method or whatever.